# Global Unset Key: Backspace

Tags: key-bindings

I want to unset the backspace key and I tried this:

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "<backspace>"))
```

Evaluating this in the buffer gives me `nil` but still the backspace key works as expected. How to unbind this?

After unbinding when I do `C-h k` on backspace it still shows me this:

> DEL (translated from `<backspace>`) runs the command autopair-backspace,
>   which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `autopair.el'.
>
> It is bound to DEL.
>
> (autopair-backspace)
>
> Possibly delete a pair of paired delimiters.

Comment: Do you still want to keep using `autopair`?

Comment: @abo-abo Yes, but if there is a way to rebind `backspace` key to some other key in autopair and all the other modes that has some binding for `backspace key`, then that would be very nice.

Comment: This is how I'll do, `(local-unset-key (kbd "<DEL>"))` or `(global-unset-key (kbd "<DEL>"))`. Curiously, it works only in another buffer, not in `*scratch*` buffer :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured this out, this will re-map `Backspace` key to `C-h` everywhere:

```
(define-key key-translation-map [?\C-h] [?\C-?])
```

Source: [Magnar Sveen's Emacs configuration](https://github.com/magnars/.emacs.d/blob/b3ceff0633c8887442d88d5000440d2bdc07e1c5/settings/key-bindings.el#L73)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(define-key (cdar autopair--emulation-alist) (kbd "DEL") nil)
```

This looks very non-standard, by the way.

### update:

Alright, here's a weird fix:

```
(setcdr (car autopair--emulation-alist)
        '(keymap (93 . autopair-skip-close-maybe)
          (91 . autopair-insert-opening)
          (41 . autopair-skip-close-maybe)
          (40 . autopair-insert-opening)
          (34 . autopair-insert-or-skip-quote)
          (13 . autopair-newline)))
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work.

Comment: Try to eval this in `*scratch*`. `autopair--emulation-alist` is buffer-local.

Comment: Tried it in `*scratch*`, but doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an answer to your question since it doesn't *unset* the <kbd>DEL</kbd> binding, but the following piece of code should shadow any existing binding (whether defined by `autopair` or any other minor/major mode or the global map):

```
(defun do-nothing ()
  "Don't do anything"
  (interactive))

(define-minor-mode no-backspace-mode
  "Disable the backspace key"
  :global t
  :lighter " noBackspace")

(defvar no-backspace--emulation-alist
  `((no-backspace-mode
     . ,(let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
          (define-key map (kbd "DEL") #'do-nothing)
          map)))) 

(add-to-list 'emulation-mode-map-alists 'no-backspace--emulation-alist)
```

When `no-backspace-mode` is active, the <kbd>DEL</kbd> key should not do anything. It should work as usual when `no-backspace-mode` is inactive.